# Updating a page won't have any effect

Tags: updates, revisions

I tried to update my about-us page by aligning all the picture to the right. And deleted some spaces to make the page tight.

But update clicking UPDATE button and view the page I still get the same old version of the page.

I checked the revisions and it indicated that I made changes/revisions a minute ago.

What could have been the cause of this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a caching plugin installed?

Comment: And clear your browser's cache too.